# SharePoint - Custom Dataview - Link Rendering Issues

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a custom SharePoint page with several dataviews. The dataviews essentially filter documents matching a certain criteria from a document library and display a link to the document along with some other meta data.

The problem I have is that when a document has a single quote in it's title, the character is being rendered as &#39; and invalidating the link. This is the code within my custom page that is displaying the invalid link.

```
<A onfocus="OnLink(this)" HREF="{@FileRef}" onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'','','','','{ddwrt:ListProperty(&quot;DefaultItemOpen&quot;)}','{ddwrt:MapToControl(&quot;&quot;, string())}','{@HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type}','','{ddwrt:GetUserID('CheckoutUser')}','{$Userid}','{ddwrt:ListProperty(&quot;ForceCheckout&quot;)}','{$FieldIDA5KNTB}','{ddwrt:CurrentRights()}')"><xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:UrlBaseName(string(@LinkFilename))" /></A>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on how I can ensure the @FileRef variable is encoded correctly before being rendered?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use the ServerURL or EncodedAbsUrl properties, this guys written it out already:

[Itay Shakury's blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itaysk/archive/2008/07/25/sharepoint-designer-data-form-web-part-apostrophe-bug.aspx)

Comment: This worked spot on thanks Adrian. Still working on my rep otherwise I'd be voting it up. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Abs, still finding my feet lo!